# How do I accept a null line?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have a line of code that sometimes does not exist.

```
HtmlElement Pend = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphRoblox_AlreadyRequestedInvite");
```

Here is the rest of my code

```
string PendT;
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphRoblox_JoinGroup").InvokeMember("click");
HtmlElement Pend =  webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphRoblox_AlreadyRequestedInvite");
PendT = Pend.InnerText;
Debug.WriteLine(PendT);

if (PendT == "Join Pending")
{
  Debug.WriteLine("Join Pending");
  Value = 1;
}
```

Now what I need help with is sometimes Pend is null and when I go to do `PendT = Pend.InnerText;` I get System.NullReferenceException. And that's probably because it cannot find Pend. Is there I way I can assign Pend a string value if it's null? I have tried

```
if (webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphRoblox_AlreadyRequestedInvite").InnerText != null)
{
Debug.WriteLine("Join Pending");
Value = 1;
}
```

Although that hasn't worked.

Comment: Something like `PendT = Pend == null ? "Oh noez" : PendT.InnerText;`?

Answer (score 0):

You could check if `Pend` is null after you retrieve it. Do what you want with taht if check.

```
string PendT;
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphRoblox_JoinGroup").InvokeMember("click");
HtmlElement Pend =  webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphRoblox_AlreadyRequestedInvite");

if(Pend != null)
{
  PendT = Pend.InnerText;
  Debug.WriteLine(PendT);

  if (PendT == "Join Pending")
  {
    Debug.WriteLine("Join Pending");
    Value = 1;
  }
}
else
{
  // do something here
}
```

Comment: Sort of works. I don't get an error anymore although when PendT is = to "Join Pending" it still thinks it's not and does the code I have in the else.

Comment: Could it be that I'm having it check after I have my program click a button which determines if the element is null or not? And it just doesn't have enough time to update the page?